# How to convert data from [-1,1] to [0,255]?

Tags: matlab, transform, rescale

I have some arrays of data in range [-1,1] and need to convert them to range [0,255] in Matlab. Either formula or code! (I checked Matlab functions but i could not find any function related to this conversion!)

Comment: Please post what you have done so far

Comment: You'll be looking at something like applying `x = (x + 1) * 255 / 2` to each element. Commenting since I know squat about Matlab but more than enough about math :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo - That's how you'd implement it in MATLAB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this small piece of exmaple code.

```
n = 10;
a = 2*rand(1,n) - 1; % some random data in [-1,1]
b = 255/2*(a+1); % linear projection to [0,255]
```